# Deleting a document and its referenced documents in mongoose v7.2.2

Tags: node.js, mongoose, middleware

I have a `User` model and `Post`, `Comment` model where `Post.author` and `Comment.author` reference `User._id`...

How can I add a middleware to delete all posts and comments when a user is deleted...

I have seen other questions on stackoverflow with answers involving `schema.pre("remove"...`, but now `.remove()` has been deprecated...

My desired implementation:

```
UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
...
})

PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String // User._id
...
})

CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String // User._id
    post: String // Post._id
...
})

UserSchema.post("findOneAndDelete", async (doc) => {
    await Post.deleteMany({ author: doc._id });
    await Comment.deleteMany({ author: doc._id });
})

PostSchema.post("deleteMany", async (doc) => {
    await Comment.deleteMany({ post: doc._id })
})
```

How can I achieve this in mongoose v7.2.2?

Comment: Can you check this answer? https://stackoverflow.com/a/59215422/11717458

Comment: Your solution works for `findByIdAndDelete` and `findOneAndDelete` but not `deleteMany`.

Comment: but you need to delete a user, where do you need deleteMany?

Comment: When I delete a user, the the middleware should delete all the referenced posts... and each post deletes all its referenced comments...

Comment: My answer does exactly the same, it uses  deleteMany

Comment: I have edited my questoin to better explain it...